# Inserir uma nova coluna em dataframe igual outra coluna só que sem caracteres especiais

Tags: python

EX:

[[image: [1]]
Coluna referência x Coluna nova retirar caracteres especiais em uma nova coluna usando pandas dataframe]

Comment: Essa pergunta não faz parte do escopo deste site. Sugiro que leia aqui: [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) e tambem leia: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala meu querido, bom dia, tudo bem?

Se eu entendi o que você deseja, pode ser feito desta forma:

```
tabela['NOVACOL'] = tabela['COLUNAREF'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('/','')
                                          .replace('.','')
                                          .replace(';','')
                                          .replace(' ',''))
```

Você atribui a uma nova coluna `tabela['NOVACOL']`, a coluna anterior `tabela['COLUNAREF']` com uma função aplicada com o lambda, usa o `replace` com os atributos, caracter que deseja substituir e substitudo(vazio) .

Não consegui adicionar o loop for na função lambda, para que substitua o caracter a ser removido por um iterador de uma lista de caracteres por exemplo, o que deixaria o código mais pythonico e limpo.

Espero que ajude, abraço.

Claudio.